# Upload Multiple images in Laravel using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload image using vue.js in Laravel for that i'm using this link

> https://jsfiddle.net/b412ruzo/

to upload image using vue.js and when i submit the form i'm getting following image in files array

[image]

now issue is that i cannot get this file array in laravel controller

when i print

```
$request->file('files')
```

in my controller i am getting null.
and when i print $request->input('files') this is the result, an empty array

[image]

Any help regarding this issue is highly appreciated.

> Code Snippet :

```
data() {
     return {
    rawData: [],
    formData: new Form({
        files:[],
})
..

  const header = {
             Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
            };
  this.formData
        .post(APP_URL + `/api/post`, { headers: header })
        .then((response) => {

   }
```

Comment: add your ajax code where your sending file

Comment: @KamleshPaul: Added code snippet, Please check, i can retrieve other fields value but issue is for only image

Comment: why your not using axios .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul: it was old code and previously image was uploaded with plugin, but now i want to upload it with custom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure you can send ajax request via  `this.formData.post`

try this

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      option: {
        maxFileCount: 3
      },
      files:[],
      rawData: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loaddropfile: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
        alert('ok')
        console.log(e)
    },
    openinput: function() {
        document.getElementById("vue-file-upload-input").click();
    },
    addImage: function(e) {
        const tmpFiles = e.target.files
      if (tmpFiles.length === 0) {
        return false;
      }
      const file = tmpFiles[0]
      this.files.push(file)
      const self = this
        const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        self.rawData.push(e.target.result)
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    },
    removeFile: function(index) {
        this.files.splice(index, 1)
      this.rawData.splice(index, 1)
      document.getElementById("vue-file-upload-input").value = null
    },
    upload: function() {
        alert('Check console to see uploads')
        console.log(this.files)
      axios.post(`${APP_URL}/api/post`,{files:this.files},{ headers: header })
        .then((response) => {});

    }
  },
  mounted(){

  }
})
```

it will send your form data to `files` key so you can get all the files via `$request->file('files')`

Comment: I'm getting message: "Unauthenticated." 401 after using axios

Comment: I have valid token {Authorization: "Bearer Gx6j7U4No1P73jKawvV0KjXIFRiYG8eoSJsZVtBcksA…meIMTD5XBaIpCooIA9C8RBsEOsjTBLlrGhQp04m7nKNelnAHy"} when i remove axios it works

Comment: tried with axios also getting null in  dd($request->file('files'));

Comment: try `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Added output it is returning same result for file field but getting other fields Is there any issue in Vue.js code that is provided in the above fiddle link

Comment: i have copy your code form jsfiddle and added axios call make sure use as it is